# Adding Edge and Vertices to already made graph?

Tags: graphics, functions, graphs-and-networks, code-request

I have a notebook that generates a hexagonal grid graph and its vertex connectivity, coordinates, and numbers as an input for an FEA program in matlab. I simply want to add members to this shape (or any other shapes) after the graph has been generated. Here is an example of my chain of hexagons.
[image]

Now, after the graph has been generated using this code:

```
HexagonalGridGraph2[{wide1_Integer?Positive, wide2_Integer?Positive, 
   wide3_Integer?Positive}, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
 Module[{cells, edges, vertices}, cells =
   Flatten[
    Table[CirclePoints[{Sqrt[3] (1 j + k - 2) + Sqrt[3] (1 j + l - 2),
         3 k - 2 - 3 l}, {2, \[Pi]/2}, 6]*5/2, {j, wide1}, {k, 
      wide2}, {l, wide3}], 2];
  
  edges = Union[Sort /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ cells, 1]];
  
  vertices = Union[Flatten[edges, 1]];
  
  IndexGraph[
   Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges, opts, 
    VertexCoordinates -> Thread[vertices -> vertices]]]
  ]
hc = HexagonalGridGraph2[{6, 1, 1}, VertexLabels -> "Index", 
  EdgeLabels -> "Index"]
```

I want to add in a little element on either side of this like so:

[image]

Ideally I would have the amount of unit shapes in a row and then add a vertex between nodes 25 and 26 as well as 2 and 5 with an edge proceeding outward from those nodes at a specified length.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can add  new vertices/edges using [`EdgeAdd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeAdd.html), and use [`GraphEmbedding[hc]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphEmbedding.html) to compute the desired vertex coordinates for new vertices:

```
newverts = VertexCount[hc] + Range[4];

coords = {{-5, 0} + #, #, #2, {5, 0} + #2} & @@ 
   (Mean @ GraphEmbedding[hc][[#]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {25, 26}});

newedges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[newverts, 2];

EdgeAdd[hc, newedges, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join[GraphEmbedding[hc], coords], 
 EdgeStyle -> {Alternatives @@ newedges -> Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

If you want to add the red lines as annotation without changing the graph `hc` you use the option `Epilog` to add any desired graphics primitives:

```
Graph[hc, 
 Epilog -> 
  {Red, 
   Line[{#, Offset[{50, 0}, #]}] & @ Mean @ GraphEmbedding[hc][[{25, 26}]], 
   Green, 
   Line[{#, Offset[{-50, 0}, #]}] & @ Mean @ GraphEmbedding[hc][[{2, 5}]]},
 ImageSize -> 600, ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {3, 3}}]
```

[image]

You can replace `Offset[{-50, 0}, #]` (`Offset[{50, 0}, #]`) with `Scaled[{-.1, 0},#]`  (respectively, `Scaled[{.1, 0},#]`) to get a similar result.